# Mongoose - 2dspehere index on array not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose and creating 2dsphere index with array of locations inside each object.

Model

```
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const OfferSchema = new Schema({
  locations: [
    {
      type: { type: String },
      coordinates: {
        type: [Number]
      }
    }
  ]
});

OfferSchema.index({ locations: '2dsphere' });
module.exports = mongoose.model('Offer', OfferSchema);
```

Example Data , an object that has 2 points in the locations array

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dbd692325cd550b3498b0e7"),
    "locations" : [ 
        {
            "coordinates" : [ 
                31.198102, 
                30.03578
            ],
            "_id" : ObjectId("5dbd692325cd550b3498b0e9"),
            "type" : "Point"
        }, 
        {
            "coordinates" : [ 
                31.097657, 
                30.04486
            ],
            "_id" : ObjectId("5dbd692325cd550b3498b0e8"),
            "type" : "Point"
        }
    ],

    "__v" : 0
}
```

Using query to find that object

```
Offer.find({
  locations: [
    {
      $near: {
        $maxDistance: 9000000,
        $geometry: {
          type: 'Point',
          coordinates: [31.213133, 30.045435]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

result is empty `[]`
expected output is the above example object.
any idea what goes wrong ?

Comment: Show a reproducible example, being documents you expect to match, the schema implemented and what the actual result is. Rest assured this does in fact work, though probably not full how you would expect and I would strongly advise against locations within an array, but it does work nonetheless. You simply have done something wrong, so showing the full case that reproduces it allows us to spot what you did wrong exactly.

Comment: Ahh. You broke GeoJSON and the index actually fails to create, though mongoose will not tell you this by default. The `_id` that mongoose inserts is killing this basically you wanted `locations: [new Schema({ ..same things ...}, { _id: false })]` here to avoid the `_id` being created. You would also need to remove any currently existing. Should be a duplicate with more detail around somewhere here.